# Creating variables using method arguments

Tags: java

I am trying to write a method that can help me declare variables more easily using the method's arguments. I'm very new to java and I'm trying to make a game that would have a decent amount of images and I want to know if there is an easier way to create these BufferedImage Variables.

currently my code looks like this

```
public class Painter extends JPanel {
 BufferedImage sprite = new
 BufferedImage(60,60,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

 public void createBufImg() {
  try {
   sprite = ImageIO.read(new File("Images/SpriteSheet.png"));
   System.out.println("File read");
  } catch (IOException e) {
   System.out.println("Could not read image");
  }
 }

 @Override
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
  super.paintComponent(g);
  createBufImg();
  g.drawImage(sprite,20,20,this);
 }
}
```

and I'm looking to see if there is a way to declare the variables so it could be called more like this

```
  sprite = new createBufImg(Images/SpriteSheet.png);
```

Comment: To answer your 2nd question, you can change createBufImg to take the filename as an argument & return the sprite as the return value.  The signature would be "public sprite createBufImg(fileName)".  then you can call it like this sprite = createBufImg(imageLocation);

Comment: In the code above, you don't *declare* any variables at all.  You declare a class, a field `sprite`, a method `createBufImg`, a method `paintComponent`, and it's parameter `g`. A variable declaration would be `String a` in `void foo() { String a; .....}`. Just so you know ;-)

Comment: BTW, there's no point in initialising the `sprite` field, if you're replacing it inside  the `createBufImg`method anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Make the method take a String (filePath) as a parameter. Set the return type to BufferedImage. Then use that string in the constructor of file.

```
public BufferedImage createBufImg(String filePath) {
    try {
        return ImageIO.read(new File(filePath));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Could not read image");
    }
    return null;
 }
```

You can then call the method like this:

```
sprite = createBufImg("Images/SpriteSheet.png");
```

Comment: He wants the method to return I believe not just a method to set a variable.

Comment: No problem. Good luck to you.

Answer (score -2):

Just leave out the `new` in the `createBufImg` call, and make it return a `BufferedImage` that will be created in the method:

```
public BufferedImage createBufImg(File imagePath) {
    try {
        return ImageIO.read(imagePath);
    } catch (IOException e) {
         // handle exception, and either throw an exception or return something appropriate
    }
}

...
BufferedImage myImage1 = createBufImage(path1);
BufferedImage myImage2 = createBufImage(path2);
```